# Cannot click on elements programmatically in WhatsApp web

Tags: javascript, automation, webdriver, browser-automation, katalon-recorder

Why it is not possible to click on any element on WhatsApp web (https://web.whatsapp.com) using JavaScript `.click()` method? The steps I am taking are mentioned below:

1. Assuming that the QR code verification is completed, visit https://web.whatsapp.com
2. Find the search bar that says *Search or start new chat*, which is an input element, and trigger `.click()` on it.

I am able to find the search input field because it has a unique *title* value *Search or start new chat*, but when I try to click it in Chrome's DevTools console, nothing happens.

First I thought that I might be firing click on the wrong element. To be sure, I installed the Katalon Recorder automation extension on Chrome. Then I recorded the steps taken (browse to WhatsApp web, click on search box). Playing the routine in Katalon clicks the search box as expected. I copied the Xpath expression recorded by Katalon and pasted the whole thing to `document.evaluate()`. Turns out, it was the same input element captured by `querySelectorAll`.

In the browser-console, I'm running this code:

```
let xPath = "(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Search or start new chat'])[1]/following::input[1]";
let result = document.evaluate(xPath, document);
let searchBox = result.iterateNext();
searchBox.click();
```

So, do you have any idea why `.click()` is not working on WhatsApp web? I would also like to know what Katalon does differently - allowing it to click on the desired element. Can I do that in a headless browser?

Comment: Can you add the code you are trying to use?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO Question updated with code.

Comment: Looks like ``searchBox `` comes as null

Comment: Not in my case: https://imgur.com/a/nF5NSbR

Comment: what are you expected to happen?

Comment: @V.Sambor The search box should get the focus and the blinking cursor should appear.

Comment: waiting for an answer in 2019

Comment: Not working for me either. I had Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77470302/is-there-anything-special-in-the-following-dom-that-makes-it-non-clickable?noredirect=1#comment136577543_77470302

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is on triggering an event via js and a `new Event()`
For this to work you will need to trigger a focus event followed by a click event.

```
let xPath = "(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Buscar o empezar un chat nuevo'])[1]/following::input[1]";
let result = document.evaluate(xPath, document);
let searchBox = result.iterateNext();

var eventFocus = new Event('focus');
var eventClick = new Event('click');
searchBox.dispatchEvent(eventFocus);
searchBox.dispatchEvent(eventClick);
```

Also I had to change `Search or start new chat` to spanish, my default language `Buscar o empezar un chat nuevo`. So something you can think of to improve your code.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: run the code on your console, and then ``alt+tab`` to your window

Comment: Can you see the blinking cursor after executing the script above?

Comment: yes, if you want we can connect via discord. Ill be more than happy to help you

Comment: Did you get the answer @DevashishJaiswal? I will be very grateful if you can share it with us. I mam able to focus on the search box but WhatsApp did not respond to input typed via console.

Comment: @AbhinavSuthar I ended up using Selenium and saved a lot of time in the process :) If you are looking for a JavaScript based solution, check out puppeteer.

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal will do!

Comment: Not working for me either. I had Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77470302/is-there-anything-special-in-the-following-dom-that-makes-it-non-clickable?noredirect=1#comment136577543_77470302